# Make player stop in front of invisible platform

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, game-physics

so I have a 2d platformer in the works, and I'd like to add walls and platforms to it, but when I try to make a platform, it doesn't stop the player in front of it if they just walk forward, and instead it makes it sort of like a step/stairs.

Here's what I have so far:

```js
var ctx, controller, rectangle, loop;

ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

// Screen size
ctx.canvas.height = 200;
ctx.canvas.width = 400;

// Position of Player
rectangle = {
  height: 25,
  jumping: true,
  width: 25,
  x: 10,
  x_velocity: 0,
  y: 0,
  y_velocity: 0
};

controller = {
  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  keyListener: function(event) {
    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 37: // Left
        controller.left = key_state;
        break;
      case 39: // Right
        controller.right = key_state;
        break;
      case 38: // Up
        controller.up = key_state;
        break;
    };
  }
};

loop = function() {
  if (controller.up && rectangle.jumping == false) {
    rectangle.y_velocity -= 25;
    rectangle.jumping = true;

  };

  if (controller.left) {
    rectangle.x_velocity -= 0.75;
  };

  if (controller.right) {
    rectangle.x_velocity += 0.75;
  };

  // Gravity
  rectangle.y_velocity += 1.5;
  rectangle.x += rectangle.x_velocity;
  rectangle.y += rectangle.y_velocity;

  // Friction
  rectangle.x_velocity *= 0.75;
  rectangle.y_velocity *= 0.75;

  // Floor
  if (rectangle.y > 150 - 25) {
    rectangle.jumping = false;
    rectangle.y = 150 - 25;
    rectangle.y_velocity = 0;
  };

  // Platform
  if (rectangle.y > 145 - 25 && rectangle.x > 150 - 25) {
    rectangle.jumping = false;
    rectangle.y = 145 - 25;
    rectangle.y_velocity = 0;
  };

  // Background
  var bg = new Image;
  bg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/He3uld9.png";
  bg.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
  };

  // Player
  var ply = new Image;
  ply.src = "https://i.imgur.com/G4UUkIl.png";
  ply.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(ply, rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
  };

  // Floor
  var fl = new Image;
  fl.src = "https://i.imgur.com/OoKP4Mm.png";
  fl.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(fl, 0, 150);
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener);
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

The commented part that says Platform under the JS section is where my code for the platform currently is. As of now, it doesn't have an image or object for you to see it, but if you play the game, it is an invisible platform right above the floor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to maintain a `blockedRight` and a `blockedLeft` property on the rectangle according to the zone you're in ? For instance, I have implemented a `blockedRight` boolean in the below where for **Platform** region, I turn it to `true` and for a **Valid Region** , I turn it back to `false`. Also I add this condition check in `controller.right` check as well.

So for an obstacle region that comes , you can make a condition that if the person is `blockedRight` and it tries to jump, you will set the `blockedRight` again to false. I am assuming the obstacles will be always taken care by `jumping` unless you have those which are greater than your **jump height** where more checks come in place.

```js
var ctx, controller, rectangle, loop;

ctx = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("2d");

// Screen size
ctx.canvas.height = 200;
ctx.canvas.width = 400;

// Position of Player
rectangle = {
  height: 25,
  jumping: true,
  width: 25,
  x: 10,
  x_velocity: 0,
  y: 0,
  y_velocity: 0,
  blockedRight:false
};

controller = {
  left: false,
  right: false,
  up: false,
  keyListener: function(event) {
    var key_state = (event.type == "keydown") ? true : false;
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 37: // Left
        controller.left = key_state;
        break;
      case 39: // Right
        controller.right = key_state;
        break;
      case 38: // Up
        controller.up = key_state;
        break;
    };
  }
};

loop = function() {
  if (controller.up && rectangle.jumping == false) {
    rectangle.y_velocity -= 25;
    rectangle.jumping = true;

  };

  if (controller.left) {
    rectangle.x_velocity -= 0.75;
    
  };

  if (controller.right && !rectangle.blockedRight) {
    rectangle.x_velocity += 0.75;
  };

  // Gravity
  rectangle.y_velocity += 1.5;
  rectangle.x += rectangle.x_velocity;
  rectangle.y += rectangle.y_velocity;

  // Friction
  rectangle.x_velocity *= 0.75;
  rectangle.y_velocity *= 0.75;

  // Floor
  if (rectangle.y > 150 - 25) {
    rectangle.jumping = false;
    rectangle.y = 150 - 25;
    rectangle.y_velocity = 0;
  };

  // Valid ground
   if(rectangle.x <= 150 - 25){
   rectangle.blockedRight = false;
   }
  // Platform
  if (rectangle.y > 145 - 25 && rectangle.x > 150 - 25) {
    rectangle.blockedRight = true;
    rectangle.jumping = false;
    rectangle.y = 145-25;
    rectangle.y_velocity = 0;
  };

  // Background
  var bg = new Image;
  bg.src = "https://i.imgur.com/He3uld9.png";
  bg.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);
  };

  // Player
  var ply = new Image;
  ply.src = "https://i.imgur.com/G4UUkIl.png";
  ply.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(ply, rectangle.x, rectangle.y);
  };

  // Floor
  var fl = new Image;
  fl.src = "https://i.imgur.com/OoKP4Mm.png";
  fl.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(fl, 0, 150);
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", controller.keyListener);
window.addEventListener("keyup", controller.keyListener);
window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);
```

```html
<canvas style="border: 1px solid black;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Hmm, is it possible for it to just not be able to cross at the beginning of the platform, but if it jumps over `rectangle.x = 150 - 25`, it should be able to move smoothly over the platform.